# How can i modify a given graph network to achieve a fixed average degree using python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, igraph

I want to change the average degree of a given graph. Suppose i have a graph network with 14.5 average degree, now i want to change it's average degree to 12 or 16. I know that it will change the network architecture but i want to do that.

Comment: What did you try? Couldn't you just add or remove edges?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of average, if you remove a edge, the average degree will decrease by 2/|G| (|G| is a number of vertices).
If you add an edge, the average degree will increase by 2/|G|.

That way you can change the average degree.

You can also somehow remove (or add) certain vertices, to do that.

Both operations will give you just some values. (Meaning you can't reach any real number you want that way)

I don't really know what's your task, but I hope this helps.